# Stop intellisense from changing my table Alias

Tags: sybase, dbeaver

Using DBeaverEE as i type i get intellisense for table names but if I want to alias that table (I for example) if i type I then space intellisense is kicking in and changing it to some keyword. This is pretty frustrating but i don't want to completely turn off intellisense, anyone else have this problem and figure out a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way would be to turn off the auto-activate on typing option.

Go to Window > Preferences > General > Editors > SQL Editor > SQL Completion

Toward the top of the SQL Completion page there should be an option named "Activate on typing". Uncheck this box and the editor won't activate intellisense until you hit ctrl + space.

[SQL Completion Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6CIA.png)